# Feature selection in mixed data type

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have a huge data set with has a mixture of both numerical and categorical variables. I have come across various feature selection techniques focused primarily on either numerical or categorical data alone, not on a mixture of them. Is there any feature selection technique which works on such a data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for Boruta package, originally written in R but also available in python. Boruta uses Random Forest to rank features but you first have to handle all missing values in your features otherwise boruta throws error. Look here for more information :

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31112/boruta-feature-selection-package